# Current at specific frequencies in a RLC circuit

Tags: frequency, current-measurement, passive-networks

Having been given a circuit, that has a resistance R of 4.0 Ω, an inductance L of 0.50 H, and a variable capacitance in series supplying a voltage V of 200 V at a frequency fr of 50 Hz, I have calculated the capacitance to achieve resonance, and the voltages across the inductance (VL) and the capacitance (VC) at resonance.

However, now I am being asked to find the circuit current I for these frequencies (40, 45, 50, 55 and 60 Hz.) I realise that the current would not simply be 200V/4.0Ω, but I am at a loss at how to proceed.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 1):

For 50Hz you can simply use I = 200V/4Ω (special case for resonance)

But for the other cases, you should use this formula:

> I = 200V/Z
>
> Z = sqr(R^2 + (Xl + Xc)^2)
>
> Xl = 2 * pi * f * L
>
> Xc = 1 / (2 * pi * f * C)

the link which is provided from JIm Dearden's comment describes the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

The current in a series circuit is the applied voltage divided by the impedance of the series components.  Since the circuit is resonant at 50 Hz, we know that the inductive reactance will cancel out the capacitive reactance so that the impedance of the circuit is due only to the resistance which is 4 ohms. At any other frequency, you need to calculate the inductive reactance and the capacitive reactance.  Adding those to the resistance will give you the total series impedance.  The current is then the applied voltage divided by that series impedance.  Note that at any other frequency, the inductive and capacitive reactances will no longer cancel.  Thus the series impedance will not be just resistive (as at 50 Hz) but will have a reactive component.

Comment: No, this answer is wrong. The impedances can't just be added, inductive and capacitive reactances are 180 degrees out of phase so its the **difference** between them that's important. The result is still 90 degrees out of phase with the resistive component so to combine them into a single impedance value (Z) we need to find the square root of the sum of the squares, then calculate current I = V/Z   (see http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/series-circuit.html )

Comment: @JImDearden, to be sure, it *is* impedances (which are complex numbers) that are added in series.  As you correctly point out, reactance (a real number, the imaginary part of impedance), *cannot* be added to resistance as this answer above implies.